# Sublime Text - Run projects on apache tomcat without refreshing eclipse project

Tags: javascript, editor, sublimetext3

Last night only i installed sublime text 3 and found it amazing. But i have been facing one problem with it.
Before sublime i was using eclipse editor for editing code. I had created Dynamic Web Project and was running it on Apache Tomcat Server which is installed.

As most part of the project contains Javascript i thought of using Sublime text. but when i modify code in sublime and try to test application, the effects are not reflected in the application till i refresh project from eclipse.

Is there any way I can run sublime project on apache without having to go in Eclipse and refresh my project and run from there. Kind of feel like missing the whole point of using Sublime Text here!!!

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick google search....

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-52.htm

Enable auto refresh.....

Comment: That totally resolved my issue. Thanks. Appreciated.